# Is it possible to submit textarea data with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit input data but I'd like to submit data of `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`. My original code:

```
<form action="/index/output" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text_box" id="t">   
</form>

<script>
    $('#t').keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/index/output',
            data : {
                text_box : $('input:text').val()
            },
            success : function(html) {
                $('#result').html(html);
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

I changed `<input>` to `<textarea>`

```
<form action="/index/output" method="POST">
     <textarea name="text_box" id="t">  </text> 
</form>
```

but it does not work well...

Is there a problem with my ajax code?

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: have you tried using a proper selector to target your textarea?

Comment: @andrew — No! That gets the **default** value (formatted as HTML instead of text), not the current value.

Comment: `$('input:text')` is not a valid selector for textareas. You should try with just `$('textarea')` or, even better `$('[name="text_box"]')`

Comment: @Loupax — input:text is a perfectly valid jQuery selector. `'text'` would match `<text>` elements, which don't exist in HTML.

Comment: @Loupax it certainly is a valid selector ... for an input. Your selctor `$('text')` isn't valid ...it;s looking for `<text>` tag

Comment: You are right @Quentin, I corrected my comment

Comment: @Quentin ok, I learned something, seems ok if you explicitly set the innerhtml but not when the user changes it http://jsfiddle.net/3ag881hL/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('input:text').val()
```

use

```
$('textarea').val()
```

Or, even better, select it by id:

```
$('#t').val()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your selector `input:text` means "Input elements of type text" and your `<textarea>` is not an `<input>`.

Just change the selector to actually match the element.

`$('textarea')`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has no correlation to your ajax code. Instead, your jQuery-Selector doesn't target textarea elements but only input elements. To fix this, you could either tell your ajax-call to submit the whole form or fix your selector.
The selector would then look like this:

```
$('textarea').val()
```

Or like this

```
$('#t').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Since you have defined the ID as `t`so you can access it with id like this:

```
 var textData = $('#t').val();
```

send it where ever you want to send.

Answer (score -1):

by the problem is your selector,

$('input:text') => means select the text box

so use instead of

```
$('textarea') => means select textarea
```

and dont use val() method becz textarea contains large number of character so to use html() method for get the value from textarea element

and also and

```
contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
```

if you are using asp.net means , contenttype is very to import for ajax to post url

Comment: you sure about `text/plain` ??

Comment: yes you need to pass just string meant add content type as text/plain

Comment: Hi charliet, may i know i will do mistake in my code

Comment: You should only set the content-type to text/plain if you are sending a plain text formatted request (which the original code is not) and if the server is expecting a plain text formatted request (and there is no suggestion that is the case).

Comment: I have to get last word of sentence in textarea so I added `$('#t').val().split(" ").pop();` but when I use `$('#t').html().split(" ").pop();` it doesn't work..